# Rails4: How do I store images uploaded by carrierwave in private folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have uploaded images with carrierwave under the public folder.
For security reason, I'm going to change the folder to under the root.

Althogh I referred to the post [How to: Secure Upload](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-To%3A-Secure-Upload) and created carrierwave.rb, I don't know how to write the path uploaded by carrierwave.

How can I display images under private folder?

image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploaader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

end
```

I created \config\initializers\carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions = 0600
  config.directory_permissions = 0700
  config.root = Rails.root
end
```

I also created images_controller.rb

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
    #I tried some, but doesn't work
end
```

I have used the following view to display images.
\views\articles\ _article.html.erb

```
<% article.photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb).to_s, class: :thumb) if photo.image? %>
<% end %>
```

It would be appreciated if you could specify the code in `routes.rb`, `images_controller.rb` and `_article.html.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running through `Rails 4 In Action` and we had a similar need.   In that book they had us create a folder under the app root called "files".

Then we changed the line in your uploader from:

```
uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}
```

to

```
files/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}
```

Now, in that book, files get dropped to the `files` directory.   You then set permissions using something like `CanCanCan` or writing it yourself.   That seems to be it.   I think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Art.
I could store images in a folder. I'd like to know how to display images in a folder.
It would be appreciated if you could be a little more specific about displaying images.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, maybe it will help someone as it helped me.
I think you misunderstand the explanation in the reference:
Add this route:

```
match "/uploads/photos/:id/:basename.:extension", controller: "photo", action: "send_img", via: :get
```

So every URL requests like: `/uploads/photos/1/best_ever_img.png` will be "redirected" to send_img action in `photos` controller

On your action,

class Photos
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploaader

```
def send_img
    id = params[:id]
    basename = params[:basename]
    extension = params[:extension]
    type = params[:type]
    # if you have a different environment in your dev and production, you can add each unique route
    if Rails.env.development?
        # The route to your project folder
        # My dev server is on windows Linux shell so the route is like this, you may use other development environment so just update the route
        base_url = "/mnt/c/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Desktop/Sites/"
    else
        base_url = "/home/deploy"
    end
    # Replace the `YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER` with name of yours
    path = "#{base_url}/YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/uploads/photos/image/#{id}/#{basename}.#{extension}"
    send_file path, x_sendfile: true
end
```

In your view, load the image like this:

```
<%= image_tag "uploads/photos/#{photo.id}/#{File.basename(photo.image.url)}" %>
```